# Is it a bug In Rglpk

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, glpk

I used Rglpk to solve a linear programming problem, but its results seems weird. I changed it to lpSolve, and the two results are different.

Please comment the Rglpk and uncomment lpSolve statements to change the solver to lpSolve.

```
# Lo, S.-F., & Lu, W.-M. (2009). An integrated performance evaluation of financial holding companies in Taiwan.
# European Journal of Operational Research, 198(1), 341–350. doi:10.1016/j.ejor.2008.09.006


sbm = function(X,Y)
{
    # Here X is N * m matrix, Y is N*s matrix.
    library(Rglpk)
    #     require(lpSolve)

    N = nrow(X)
    m = ncol(X)
    s = ncol(Y)

    #     variables are 
    #     t
    #     gamma_j,j=1..N
    #     s_i^(-),i=1..m
    #     s_r^(+),r=1..s

    efficiency = numeric(N)

    max_positive_y = apply(Y[,1:s], MARGIN = 2, function(x) max(x[x>0]))
    min_positive_y = apply(Y[,1:s], MARGIN = 2, function(x) min(x[x>0]))


    dir = rep("==",1+m+s+1)
    rhs = c(1,rep(0,m),rep(0,s),0)
    for(i in 1:N)
    {
        x = X[i,]
        y = Y[i,]

        #variables
        coef_t = 1
        coef_gamma = rep(0,N)
        coef_s_i = -1/(m * x)
        coef_s_r = rep(0,s)

        obj = c(coef_t,coef_gamma,coef_s_i,coef_s_r)

        coef_constraint1_s=y
        for(r in 1:s)
        {
            if(y[r]<0){
                coef_constraint1_s[r] = 
                min_positive_y[r] * (max_positive_y[r] - min_positive_y[r])/
                (max_positive_y[r] - y[r])
            }
        }

        constraint1 =     c(1,  rep(0,N), rep(0,m) ,     1/(s*coef_constraint1_s))
        constraint2 = cbind(-x, t(X),     diag(m),       matrix(0,m,s))
        constraint3 = cbind(-y, t(Y),     matrix(0,s,m), -diag(s))
        constraint4 =     c(-1, rep(1,N), rep(0,m),      rep(0,s))

        mat = rbind(constraint1,constraint2,constraint3,constraint4)

        results = Rglpk_solve_LP(obj = obj,mat = mat,dir = dir,rhs = rhs,max = FALSE)
        efficiency[i] = results$optimum
    #   results <- lp("min", obj, mat, dir, rhs)
    #   efficiency[i] = results$objval

    }
    efficiency
}
```

Comment: Please post a fully reproducible example. In particular, what are the `X` and `Y` values you passing to `sbm` that cause the different results?

Comment: Try composing the same problem as a GLPK input file and run GPLK by itself. If the result is what you expected, maybe there is some problem parsing the output back into R. Otherwise, try to find the GPLK input which is generated by R. Is it the same as yours?